# Play dependencies in offline mode?

Tags: playframework-2.0

I am working on a new web application , and behind a restricted firewall which doesn't allow me to connect to repos online . while i am trying to create a new play application it is trying to connect to Ivy repos. is there is anyway i can download all the dependencies one shot and work offline in my ide?

Answer (score 0):

Yes sure, this is possible! Several ways exist:

- If you can arrange to establish a direct Internet connection, then just issue `activator clean compile` within a terminal in your application's root directory. This will resolve and download all the required dependencies. Next set up your application to stop resolving dependencies, this can be achieved by adding `cleanKeepFiles ++= Seq("resolution-cache", "streams").map(target.value / _)` to your build.sbt file.
- Otherwise you can resolve dependencies yourself and add the required libraries as jar files in your application root's /lib folder (which should be part of your build path).